# Blog + Pagination?

Tags: pagination

Still new to EE, and am quickly losing my hair trying to get a blog going, and getting it paginated correctly.

The problem I'm having is that the pagination links move in increments of 6, /news/P6, /news/12 etc....

I've tried removing all the code except for the Title and the "Read More..." link, and pagination still has the same issue.

*** EDIT ***

I'm also looking to have only 6 entries per page, so that the next page will have the next six entries etc... 6 entries are currently showing on the /news page - which is good. The site has something like 40 entries, but I just want to paginate so only six entries show at a time.

*** /EDIT ***

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
<ul class="news">
                {exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="6" dynamic="no" orderby="date" sort="desc" paginate="bottom"}
                  {paginate}

                      <p id="pagination">Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
                    {/paginate}


                            <li>
                                <div class="pic">
                                    {if image !=""}<a href="{url_title_path='news'}"><img src="{image}" alt="{title}" /></a>{/if}
                                </div>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <h5>{title}</h5>
                                    <p>{if "{content:has_excerpt}"}{content:excerpt}{if:else}{content}{/if} 
                                    </p> 
                                    {if video_embed != ""}{video_embed}{/if}
                                     {if slideshow} 
                                    {slideshow limit="10"}<a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}" style="float:left;">{exp:ce_img:pair src="{url}" max="100" crop="yes"}<img src="{made}" alt="{title}" />{/exp:ce_img:pair}</a>{/slideshow}
                               {/if}
                                    <a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}" style="clear:all;">Read More...</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                {/exp:channel:entries}

                        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is correct for what you're wanting to achieve.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="6" dynamic="no" orderby="date" sort="desc" paginate="bottom"}
```

This code will get you 6 entries per pagination page and your pagination URLs will increment by 6 because you have `limit="6"` set. If you change that to `limit="10"`, you still see 10 entries per page and URLs that increment by 10.

Comment: If you are having an issue with 6 entries NOT showing then something else is wrong in your code. Add more details to your question and we can try to help.

Comment: Hi Anna, thanks for your suggestion. I've edited my question, perhaps my lack of knowledge is getting in the way! I have 6 entries (out of approx. 40) showing on the /news page... I'm looking to show only 6 at a time, and have the pagination navigate to the next page of entries etc...

Comment: Again, the code you posted is correct for what you want to do... What isn't working exactly??

Comment: ARGH... I don't know what happened... it's all working now. I have dynamic="yes" and limit="6". Thanks for your patience with a noob like myself.

Comment: Does it break when you change dynamic="yes" to dynamic="no"?

Comment: wow... now I have no idea what's going on... it works both ways... crazy. I must have completely overlooked something.

Comment: Perhaps it was cache or something... Note: You don't need to set dynamic="yes"... this is the default for the channel:entries tag so you can remove it. Also, you can shorted {if image !=""} to {if image} and {if video_embed != ""} to  {if video_embed}.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `limit="6"` so your paginated urls will be in increments of 6. What you have working correctly.

The `P6` in the url is basically an offset count so EE knows which entry in the count/order to begin with. `P6` will start with entry 7 in your determined order.

Comment: Ah, I see. So then how do I get only 6 entries to show per page?

Comment: Change no to `dynamic="no"` to `dynamic="yes"`

Comment: You don't have to change to dynamic="no" to dynamic="yes" here. When you have dynamic="no" set on the channel:entries tag AND you have the paginate="" parameter set, EE will act dynamically for pagination data only.